# Youtube embeded - play/pause playback

Tags: javascript, qt, youtube, embed

I would like to use a YouTube embed and make it play/pause with JavaScript Control.
I have checked the api [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)
But all theses cases refer to a iframe that you embed on **your** website, but I want to use the original YouTube URL and not create a webpage.

[See use case here (picture)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgbgw3kwcr1rfmr/youtubePlayer1.png?dl=0)

Example URL used :
https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autohide=1&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1

The problem seems to be that the iframe doesn't have an ID, so I tried many JavaScript command, but the player never pause or play with my Qt Pushbutton.

Any advice appreciated!

```
QString jsValue = "document.getElementById('ytplayer').pauseVideo();";
ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(jsValue);
```

Comment: Short question : Can I use javascript to play/pause this video? (using youtube site and not embedded it) :
https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autohide=1&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1

Comment: To motivate discussion.. will pay some 1000 Dogecoins to anyone that can help! I'm sure it's possible to do..

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found!

YouTube generate a unique ID that you first have to retrieve

```
QWebElement player = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst("div[id=\"player\"]");

QWebElement embed = player.findFirst("embed");

QString embedID = embed.attribute("id");
QString jsToExecute = QString("document.getElementById('%1').playVideo();").arg(embedID);
ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(jsToExecute);
```